# Differentiation of tanx gives different value

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

$\dfrac {d \tan(x)}{dx}$ at 31 gives $0.0238$ in casio calculator and using newtons forward method;
But $\sec^2(x)$ gives $1.3610$

Comment: From doing some research, it appears these calculators have some issues with them when it comes to finding derivatives of trig functions in degree mode. Make sure the calculator is set to radians and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually both are correct if you understand that your "$\tan(x)$" isn't the usual tangent of $x$. It is "tangent of $x$ degrees" not "tangent of $x$ radians".

The derivative of $\tan(x)$ (where $x$ is measured in radians) is $\sec^2(x)$. However, if your calculator is set to a "degrees mode", the "tan" function isn't really the standard mathematical tangent function anymore.

In degrees mode "$\tan(x)$" actually means "$\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{180}x\right)$" (to convert from *unnatural* degrees units to *natural* radians).The derivative of this function is $\dfrac{\pi}{180}\sec^2\left(\dfrac{\pi}{180}x\right)$ (by the chain rule). If you plug $x=31$ degrees into this function you'll get approximately $1.3610$.

So the calculator's derivative computation is off from the "correct" answer by a factor of $\dfrac{\pi}{180}$ because in reality when you switch to degree mode your trigonometric functions are no longer the standard trig functions but instead some weird degree-mode monstrosities.

Long story short: *Don't use degree mode* for anything beyond basic evaluations. Degrees are ok for basic basic stuff, but not for any serious mathematical computations.